# where did this 2nd desktop come from, how to I move an open window back to the original?

Tags: macos, desktop, mission-control

I was deep into answering another SE question and without realizing it I sent my browser (chrome) to <s>[the corn field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/It%27s_a_Good_Life_(The_Twilight_Zone)#Plot_summary)</s> a second desktop. I'm trying to read an equation in an SE question and type it into python but they are on two different desktops, and I don't want to close either of them.

I grabbed the Chrome by the very top with my cursor and tried to slide it just a little bit to the right, but instead it moved to the second desktop with a default background. I have no idea how this happened

I've been vaguely aware that multiple desktops exist in MacOS but never used it. Now I suddenly have two questions:

1. How can I move chrome back to my "main" or normal desk top where all the other screens are open?
2. How might I have sent chrome to <s>the corn field</s> a second desktop to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s Apple’s documentations on mission control:

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204100

> 1. How can I move chrome back to my "main" or normal desk top where all the other screens are open?

Follow the directions to open Mission Control, click the desktop with the open chrome window, grab it, and move it to the desired destination desktop.

> 2. How might I have sent chrome to a second desktop to begin with?

Don't know. If it happens again, see if you can note your exact trackpad and keyboard gestures at the time and leave a comment.

[image: Use Mission Control on your Mac]